# How to increase the transparent area of PNG image up to certain sizes?

Tags: php

I have image **150x150px**. I need to make that image **800x350px** by increasing the transparent area around source image, indicating the coordinates in new image: **50px** from top, **50px** from left.

[image: source image]

[image: new image from source]

i have tried:

```
// the needed sizes of image
$imgWidth = 800;
$imgHeight = 441;

// currrent sizes of PNG image
$wmSize = getimagesize("wm2.png");
$wmWidth = $wmSize[0]; // 724
$wmHeight = $wmSize[1]; // 144

// current PNG image
$wm = imagecreatefrompng("wm2.png"); 
imagesavealpha($wm, true);
imagealphablending($wm, true);

// new empty image
$new_empty_image = imagecreate($imgWidth, $imgHeight);

// opacity 0
$transparent = imagecolorallocatealpha($new_empty_image, 255, 255, 255, 127);
imagefilledrectangle($new_empty_image, 0, 0, $imgWidth, $imgHeight, $transparent);

imagecopy($new_empty_image, $wm, $imgWidth, $imgHeight, 0, 0, $wmWidth, $wmHeight);

imagepng($new_empty_image, 'new.png');
```

But i get just empty image without source PNG image:

[image]

**so, the last working version is:**

```
$width = 800;
$height = 441;

// PNG image
list($wm_width, $wm_height) = getimagesize('wm.png');
$wm = imagecreatefrompng('wm.png');

// new empty image
$new_empty_image = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height);
$transparent = imagecolorallocatealpha($new_empty_image, 255, 255, 255, 127);
imagefill($new_empty_image, 0, 0, $transparent);

// Put wm on top of new image.
imagecopy($new_empty_image, $wm, 50, 150, 0, 0, $wm_width, $wm_height);

imagealphablending($new_empty_image, false);
imagesavealpha($new_empty_image, true);

imagepng($new_empty_image, 'new.png');
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Any code yet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a fully functional and tested example:

```
$width = 800;
$height = 441;

// PNG image
list($wm_width, $wm_height) = getimagesize('wm.png');
$wm = imagecreatefrompng('wm.png');

// new empty image
$new_empty_image = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height);
$transparent = imagecolorallocatealpha($new_empty_image, 255, 255, 255, 127);
imagefill($new_empty_image, 0, 0, $transparent);

// Put wm on top of new image.
imagecopy($new_empty_image, $wm, 50, 50, 0, 0, $wm_width, $wm_height);

// Optional??? This code seems to be needed in some system and not in others.
imagealphablending($new_empty_image, false);
imagesavealpha($new_empty_image, true)
// ?? Optional

imagepng($new_empty_image, 'new.png');
```

Comment: Looks like the image copy function should use 50, 100 instead of width, height.

Comment: Updated the anwwer again. This one works great on my local server. I change the imagecreate to imagecreattruecolor and imagefillrect with imagefill

Comment: Thanks. I have tried your code. I have got a right size image but without transparent place. Its all white around source PNG image. How can i do it trasparent??

Comment: This code does do it transparent. Works perfectly on my system. You may need to experiement with imagesavealpha and imagealphablending. Not all pngs are created equal.

Comment: A was added **imagealphablending($new_empty_image, false)**, 
**imagesavealpha($new_empty_image, true)** between two last rows and success! Thanks!